# Правильно ли я написал программу по блок-схеме?

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода

[image: блок схема]

я и сам написал код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   while (true) {
        int n, p = 0;
        cin >> n;
        while (n > 0)  {
            p = p * 10 + n % 10;
            n = n / 10;
        }
        cout << p;
          return 0;
    }
}
```

Проверьте, пожалуйста

Comment: Зачем внешний цикл? На блок-схеме его нет. Хотя из-за `return 0;` в нём нет смысла.

Comment: @EOF, таки его и в коде нет =)

Comment: @vp_arth он есть, но его как бы нет)

Comment: так программа написано верно? подскажите

Comment: Верно, но внешний цикл уберите, на всякий случай =)

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Конструкций вида `int n, p = 0;` следует избегать, вместо этого следует объявлять [по одной переменной на строке](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JztA.jpg), [всегда инициализировать переменные](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-always), [для инициализации использовать синтаксис direct list initialization](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-list). `int n{}; int p{};`

Comment: Какая связь между заголовком и текстом?

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int p = 0;
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    while (n > 0)
    {
        p = p * 10 + n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    std::cout << p;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    setlocale ;
    
    double  x , y1, y2 ,y3 ;
    cout<< "вход:";
    cin>>x;
    
    y1=sin(x)/(x*x);
    
    y2=pow(atan(x),2)+exp(pow(x,1./2));
    y3=log(x+1)/log(M_PI);
   
    if (x<0 ){
    cout<<"y1="<<y1;
    }
    else if (0<=x<=1) {
    cout<<"y2="<<y2;
    }
    else {
    cout << "y3="<<y3;
    }
    
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Как этот код относится к вопросу? У вас тут вообще другая формула.